# How do I select a concatenated name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I select a concatenated name in a jquery heres my sample code;

```
p = "WL_INVDTL.0001.LW3SUPRC";

$('input[name=p]').attr("disabled",false);
```

is it possible to select a concatenated text.

Comment: I am not getting your code example? `p` is a variable, but on line 2 you are trying to select a input field with name `p` using jquery. Where is the *concatenated* text in your example?

Comment: yes thats right, your code does not say anything

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
$('input[name="' + p '"]').prop("disabled",false);
```

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#WL_INVDTL').on('click', 'tr td:first-child input:checkbox', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('tr').find('input:text').prop('disabled', !$this.is(':checked'))
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R7gqD/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/heliosSuperman/gyEUH/1/ heres a sample of my code 
I want to disabled and enabled the last two textboxes when i click each checkbox., 
thanks  for helping guys

Comment: p = "WL_INVDTL.0001.LW3SUPRC";
  
$('input[name="' + p + '"]').prop("disabled",false);
}); 

i think this is a good answer thanks arun p johny